# Find the length of any great circle on $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

I am speculating that the length is $2\pi$ because the circumference of a unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $2\pi$. From my understanding, a great circle in  $\mathbb{S}^2$ would be a circle centered at the origin with a radius of 1.

Would anyone be able to confirm this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: would this be correct reasoning?